# xp_delete_file not working

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, extended-stored-procedure

I am running a query window under my own account and the following command:

```
DECLARE @ReturnCode int 
EXECUTE @ReturnCode = [master].dbo.xp_delete_file 0, N'\\backup\sql', 'bak', '2015-11-24T23:30:02' 
IF @ReturnCode <> 0 
 RAISERROR('Error deleting files.', 16, 1)
```

On one server this functions correctly but on another it hangs for a very long time and does not delete the files.

Is there anything in particular that could stop how this extended proc runs?

Just an update.  I have found that this proc is in the XPStar.dll and have copied that over from a working environment however its still not working.  I am wondering if I need to re-register it?  Although not sure if you can with system extended procs?

Comment: Did you check that the service accounts are the same or have the same permissions on `\\backup`? (Also, have you considered managing your old backup files outside of SQL Server? Powershell, maybe? `xp_delete_file` is undocumented and unsupported, so use at your own risk.)

Comment: Amazingly after I copied over the file and rebooted it all started working!

Comment: ...until next time it stops working.

Comment: thats the spirit ;)